# Trouble with auto layout constraints with iPhone 5 and iPhone 6

Tags: xcode6, autolayout, constraints

I am currently having some trouble auto layout constraints. I have 5 labels arrange horizontally like in the example below:

```
Ex. [ID  Name       Sex  Age  Occupation]
```

(supposed the Brackets is the edge of the screen

It look nice in the iPhone 4.0 inch. but it not look what I want in the iPhone 4.7inch and the 5.5inch.

```
Ex. iphone 4.inch look    [ID  Name       Sex  Age  Occupation]
Ex. iphone 4.7 inch look  [ID  Name       Sex  Age  Occupation    ]
Ex. iphone 5.5 inch look  [ID  Name       Sex  Age  Occupation        ]
```

There is some space at the edge for the 4.7 inch and the 5.5 inch.

Please help me how to make it all look the same as iPhone 4.0 inch.

Comment: I'm not familiar with iOS but can you not set percentage width instead?

Comment: you use storyboard or programatically give a constraints

Comment: could you give me some code or some method to do it?

Answer (score 0):

To make this layout work on all devices, you will need to set a static width for the first 4 labels and let the fifth one resize so that it fits the superView.

The constraints should be something like:

- First Label : leading space to container + width + horizontal space to 2nd label
- Second - forth label : width + horizontal space to  label
- Last label - trailing space to container

You will need for all labels also vertical constraints, but I supposed that is already working.

Let me know if you need more help